# Muffled sound with BlackShark V2 X in War Thunder

Tags: audio-hardware, war-thunder

I recently got a new pair of BlackShark V2 X headphones, and the 7.1 surround sound is iffy at best in *War Thunder*. The machine gun and main cannon fire are pretty muffled. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've been looking for some EQ software but have managed to find none.

Comment: You need to add more details. What kind of headphones did you get? Can you show the internals of the headphones (if possible)?

Comment: What about other games/applications/videos?

Comment: @TimMcYeah The headphones are Blackshark V2 X. It's in the title :)

Comment: Could people at least give a reason as to why they downvoted a question ?

Comment: @TimmyJim I was using the razer 7.1 app and in most stuff like video or even other games it sounds fine. In warthunder it sounds kind of muffled, like inside a barrel or something.

Comment: How about trying different headphones to see if its truly the headphones or the game?

Comment: @TimmyJim I did use a cloud II hyperx headset until I got these. The sound in game was fine. I downloaded EQ APO and set some settings and now I am getting acceptable audio in WT

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your question @CodeJunkie